# prove f is a contraction mapping

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Prove that a continuously differentiable function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a contraction mapping if $|f'(x)| <1$ for all $x \in[0,1]$

How would I go about this? I got a feel that if $f'(x)$ is less than 1 for all x, the function should be below f(x) = x. But I don't think this intuitive idea is enough for a proof. Any idea of what I can do?

Comment: Use mean value theorem.

Comment: Do you mean "continuously differentiable"? I.e. that $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is continuous? It's redundant to say that $f$ is continuous if it's differentiable.

Comment: If I remember correctly, a contraction mapping is a map $f$ such that $d(f(x),f(y)) \le kd(x,y)$ where $k \in (0,1)$. You can use this plus the fact that the function is continuously differentiable.

Comment: yes I meant continuously differentiable. I fixed my question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $x\mapsto \lvert f'(x)\rvert$ maps $[0,1]\to [0,1]$ continuously. Because $[0,1]$ is compact, $\lvert f'\rvert$ achieves its maximum $M$ at some point $x_0 \in [0,1]$. By hypothesis, $\lvert f'(x_0) \rvert = M < 1$, so for all $x\in [0,1], \lvert f'(x)\rvert \le M < 1$.

Given $0 \le x < y \le 1$, by the mean value theorem there is $c \in [x,y]$ such that $f(y) - f(x) = f'(c)(y-x)$, so $\lvert f(y) - f(x)\rvert = \lvert f'(c)\rvert \lvert y-x\rvert \le M\lvert y-x\rvert$. So $f$ is a contraction mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $f$ is continuously differentiable, we may apply the extreme value theorem to get that $f'(x)$ achieves a maximum $a<1$. Thus, we can apply the mean value theorem to see that for all $x,y\in[0,1]$, $$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(c)\leq a<1,$$ for some $x<c<y$. Thus, $f(x)-f(y)\leq a(x-y)$. This fact, combined with $[0,1]$ being complete gives us that $f$ is a contraction map.