# Are mappings $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $|f'(x)| < 1$ contractions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

This is an extension of this question found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502871/prove-f-is-a-contraction-mapping). Can we safely assume that all differentiable maps $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $|f'(x)| < 1$ are contraction mappings?

For clarity, given a metric space $M$, a contraction mapping is defined as a continuous map $f: M \to M$ such that for some constant $k < 1$ and all $x, y \in M$, $$d(fx, fy) \leq kd(x,y)$$

Also, contraction mappings are contrasted with *weak* contractions, which are functions similarly defined, but only with the requirement that $$d(fx, fy) < d(x,y)$$
Progress so far: I've tried constructing counterexamples that have derivatives that approach 1 asymptotically but to no avail. Most of the counterexamples require that the function $f$ contain $log$ or $\frac{1}{x^n}$ terms, which are not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, and so contradict the requirement that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Good question. $\;\!$

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem, any such function is a weak contraction.

To find an example which is not a (strong) contraction, just pick any continuous function $g : \Bbb{R} \to (-1, 1)$ which satisfies $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 1$. Then

$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g(t) \, dt $$

will serve as a counter-example. For example, if we choose $g(x) = x^2/(1+x^2)$ then

$$f(x) = x - \arctan x $$

is a counter-example by the mean value theorem.

Comment: Wait. In this case, wouldn't the Lipschitz constant be 1, since the limit of the $\frac{x^2}{1+ x^2}$ is 1? Wouldn't that in turn imply that this is NOT a contraction map?

Comment: @AnanthRaviKumar, That is exactly what I am claiming: there exists a differentiable function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ with $|f'| < 1$ which is *not* a contraction.